# Explain '' Lagrangian interpolating method has complexity $ \ O(N^2) \ $ ''

Tags: numerical-methods

Building an interpolation polynomial by solving a linear system has a complexity  $ \ O(N^3) \ $ and  that of Lagrangian interpolating method  has complexity $ \  O(N^2) \ $.

What does mean it ?

Explain in short way.

**Answer:**

I think when solving a linear system through Lagrangian interpolating method , there arises $ O(N^2) \ $ calculations.

Is it correct ?

If not then what would be the  true answer?

Comment: If $N$ is the number of data points, then we require on the order of $N^2$ operations when solving using Lagrange interpolation.